# WordPress 404 Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update wordpress and i'm seeing these errors:

> Apache Server at www.3cdesignsolutions.com Port 80
>
> The requested URL /wp-admin/your_website_url_here/wp-admin/upgrade.php
>   was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Anybody know what file I need to edit? Where can I enter in my website url?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fix this mistake in the database directly, since you can't log in to the wp-admin to do it there. Find the row for the `siteurl` option in the `wp_options` table and fix its value.

Comment: Where's your "That was Easy!" button when you need it? ;)

Comment: where is this siteurl option?